# UIView Animation not working in iOS 7, working properly in IOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, ios7, uiview

This code works properly in iOS 8, but does nothing in iOS 7.

```
    -(void)displayButtons{
xMasOrig=_btnAgregarIpad.center.x;
yMasOrig=_btnAgregarIpad.center.y;
CGPoint newPosition1 = CGPointMake(_btnDespliegaIpad.center.x -35.0f -_btnDespliegaIpad.frame.size.width/2.0f + _btnCuenta2Ipad.frame.size.width/2.0f, _btnCuenta2Ipad.center.y);
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
    _btnAgregarIpad.center=newPosition1;
}];
```

}

Any idea of how can I get it to work? Thanks.

Comment: Show more of the surrounding code, please. You are probably cancelling the animation by setting the frame or center of this button.

Comment: Just updated with the whole method

Comment: The code looks okay, but you are you doing other stuff you're not telling about, that might interfere with the animation server? Does this code accidentally run on a background thread? Are you doing anything else on a background thread?

Comment: Just checked with [[UIApplication sharedAplication] applicationState]==UIApplicationStateBackground, and it returns false. Also this button I'm trying to animate its part of the header of a sliding menu created with SWRevealViewController. I don't know if that helps.

Comment: UIApplicationStateBackground has nothing to do what thread we are running on...

Comment: You're right. Just checked with [NSThread isMainThread], and it seems to be running on the background. Thanks

Comment: Cool! I hope this leads to some sort of solution. You must not try to touch the interface on a background thread, so you will need to step out to main thread to make this method call.